# Alternative for creating dataframe inside foreach

Tags: apache-spark, hive, rdd

I have a JavaPairRDD on which I want to iterate, perform some operation and store output to Hive. Currently, I am trying to create a Dataframe inside the foreach which is throwing an exception since Dataframe is not creatable inside foreach. So what alternative is available?

```
        JavaPairRDD<Long, Iterable<EmployeeDetail>>  employeeDetailPairList = fetchEmployeeDetailData();
        List<EmployeeZone> employeeZoneFCList = fetchEmployeeZoneData();
        employeeDetailPairList.foreach(employeeDetailPair ->  {
            Iterable<EmployeeDetail> employeeDetailList = employeeDetailPair._2;
            Set<String> zipCodeSet = StreamSupport.stream(employeeDetailList.spliterator(), false).map(e -> e.getZipCode()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            List<EmployeeZone> employeeZoneFilteredList = employeeZoneList.stream().filter(e -> zipCodeSet.contains(String.valueOf(e.getLoc()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<Output> outputListList = processEmployeeData(employeeZoneFilteredList);
            outputListList = addWeekStartDay(outputListList, weekStartDay);
            if(outputListList != null && this.getSession()!= null) {
              Dataset<Row> recordsDF = this.getSession().sqlContext().createDataFrame(outputListList, Output.class);
              recordsDF.write().insertInto(SHIPCODE_PREFERRED_FC_HIVE_TABLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create DataFrame inside a transformation. The only way to achieve this is to join Hivetable with the RDD. This way you can avoid lookup and perform operation you need.Hope it answer your question